# How does Riker's brain retain his full personality and memories after being un-shrunken?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the *TNG* episode "[Genesis](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Genesis_%28episode%29)", Riker's devolution leaves him with a brain that is "much smaller" than its original mass and/or volume.  Yet, when the crew re-evolves into their previous genetic selves, his memories, cognition, and personality are all perfectly intact.

Is this just a sloppy story, or am I missing something about the plot resolution?

**Clarification:**  I do realize that intelligence is not directly a function of brain size.  I'm just wondering how his memories and previous sense of "self" could remain intact after such drastic transformations of his brain.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not one of my favourite episodes.  Every time I watch it (and "Masks", two episodes earlier in the season), I think to myself, "They're definitely running out of good ideas.  I'm happy they decided to quite while they were ahead!"

Comment: I agree with Praxis - this episode was even worse than the TOS one with the women who stole Spock's brain (at least that one had a certain [narm charm](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NarmCharm) .

Comment: ["His cranial plates have thickened by twenty percent. His brain is much smaller, sir. I do not believe he can comprehend our language."](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/271.htm)

Comment: Riker's a pretty big guy. 45% of normal size might still be enough brain for him to function.

Comment: Out of universe, [brain size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_size#Animals) is more closely related to body size than intelligence.  Elephants have much larger brains than humans, for example.  And Neanderthals had larger brains than humans.

Comment: They used the antibodies in Spot's amniotic fluid to create an antidote that restored everyone back to normal. It's Trek-science and it does not have to make sense. But I agree that in this episode not only the crappy science makes loyal fans weep.

Comment: I can assume they were working on the theory that humans only use 15% or their brain or something. So a brain reduced to 45% could still contain everything of value; it just has less spare room.

Comment: @Izkata : I'm aware of that.  I realize that intelligence is not directly a function of brain size.  I'm just wondering how his memories and previous sense of "self" could remain intact after such a transformation.

Comment: It's not like Riker was the brains of the operation to start with

Comment: While it wasn't stated in the episode, maybe we could imagine that the transporters had stored information about Riker's large scale brain structure...in the episode "Rascals" where they were transformed into kids, when they transformed back Beverly Crusher said "I'm loading the adult patterns into the buffer". And in "Lonely among us" when Picard turned himself into energy and beamed into a cloud, Data said "I knew we had to have the Captain's physical pattern here, sir. He was the last one to beam out."

Comment: @Hypnosifl : A very elegant and plausible solution to a gaping plot hole in a silly episode.  :-)

Comment: I can imagine 3 solutions:

1. They modified the deflector dish or polarized it
2. They used the transporter
3. They used the "particle of the week" beam.

I think method 2. is the likeliest one. They restored his brain from an older transporter log. Normaly it is not possible to store a pattern of living people digitally, because they are too complex and could only stored for a short time analog in the transporter buffer. But perhaps Rikers brain isn't that complex.

Comment: Good thing Spot changed genders for this episode!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire episode concept was flawed.  Riker devolved into something that is not even in human evolutionary history (Neanderthal was a parallel species with humans).  So keeping this in mind, and putting it to once side, the answer is simple.  <strike>Bones waved a salt shaker</strike> Crusher performed neurosurgery on him, once he re-evolved.

It should be noted that this episode has some of the weakest science of the entire franchise.  It is not even based on out of date science we now think is silly... its based on made up science that the writers pulled out of their ... and never fact checked.  Since the episode poses an illogical question, it is straining to pose a logical answer.

Comment: Genetic evidence published in 2014 suggests that Neanderthals contributed to the DNA of anatomically modern humans, probably through interbreeding between 50,000 to 60,000 years ago with a population of anatomically modern humans. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal_genome_project

Comment: Interesting.  But 2014 is not 1994, so the writers just screwed that one up.

Comment: I know was a fluke on their part but though it was worth a mention.

Comment: It was never stated that Riker was turning into a Neanderthal--in fact, since Neanderthal brains were slightly larger in volume than modern humans', this wouldn't make sense. More likely it was something like Homo Erectus or Australopithecus. But there was a similar type of evolutionary error in the episode, namely Barclay turning into a spider--mammals didn't evolve from arthropods!